# mysql data into json through php

Tags: php, json

I am using json-decode within while loop. Every time it creates json code in .json file, it looks like below and I couldn't read this .json file.

```
[{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"avss","productname":"avss","2":"2920","price":"2920","3":"xasx","textarea":"xasx","4":"e3.jpg","name":"e3.jpg","5":"uploads\/e3.jpg","imagepath":"uploads\/e3.jpg"}]
```

I want it to be like this...

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Item 0",
        "price": "$0"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "price": "$1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Item 2",
        "price": "$2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Item 3",
        "price": "$3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Item 4",
        "price": "$4"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Item 5",
        "price": "$5"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Item 6",
        "price": "$6"
    }
]
```

The code:

```
global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `forms`";
$mq = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mq)){
          echo '<div class="form-group"><img src="'.$row['imagepath'].'" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:250px;height:180px">&nbsp '.             
          $row['name']."".$row['price'].'</div>';



   $emparray = array(); 
   $emparray[] = $row;
   $fp = fopen('tables/data.json', 'w');
   $k= json_encode($emparray);

   fwrite($fp,$k);
   fclose($fp);
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Where is the matching `}` for `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mq)){`?

Comment: You're emptying `$emparray()` each time in the loop. You should initialize it **before** the loop, add to the array **inside** the loop, and convert it to JSON and write to the file **after** the loop. This is simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mq, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

or

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mq)) {
```

to fetch associative array. By default `mysqli_fetch_array` will fetch both associative and numeric indices.